# Css hover animation flickering/looping

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a question about an animation.

My animation is flickering, I want to stop that trigger looping. When I hover these after and before it's like looping my animation. I've tried little things but no clue ...

Maybe should i try to do it with span (replace before) with position absolute ?

Here is the codepen : https://codepen.io/chrishanZ/pen/eYgoLBG

Thanks for helping me.

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 4;
}
.header_buttonburger {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  right: 19px;
  top: 24px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.header_buttonburger:before, .header_buttonburger:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: top 0.15s ease;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.header_buttonburger:before {
  top: calc(100% + 2px);
}
.header_buttonburger:after {
  top: calc(100% + 8px);
}
.header_buttonburger:hover:before {
  top: calc(100% + 4px);
}
.header_buttonburger:hover:after {
  top: calc(100% + 12px);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <button class="header_buttonburger">
      Menu
   </button>
  
</header>
```

If someone can help me ! :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Nothing happening in your sample?

Comment: https://codepen.io/chrishanZ/pen/eYgoLBG

Really sorry here is the codepen

Comment: What do you mean looping? I don't see any flickering or issues with the hover effect

Comment: @RolvApneseth Try to put your cursor in the middle of the two lign under the "menu"

Comment: @DUTTOOChris I see what you mean. The lines go up and down when you hover a bit above the bottom line.

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 Exactly any idea of solutions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to create a container for the button and hover on the container like this :

```
     <div class="container_header_buttonburger">
        <button class="header_buttonburger">
            Menu
        </button>
     </div>
```

and for the styles

```
     .header_buttonburger {
         position: relative;
         color: black;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-size: 1.125em;
         z-index: 3;
         display: block;
      }
          .container_header_buttonburger {
            position: absolute;
            right: 19px;
            top: 24px;
            padding-bottom:14px; /* <--that makes the difference */
          }
          .container_header_buttonburger:hover > .header_buttonburger:before {
            top: calc(100% + 4px);
          }
          .container_header_buttonburger:hover > .header_buttonburger:after {
            top: calc(100% + 12px);
          }
```

so all the styles :

```
              .header {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            background-color: blue;
            z-index: 4;
          }
          .header_buttonburger {
            position: relative;
            color: black;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 1.125em;
            z-index: 3;
            display: block;
          }
          .header_buttonburger:before, .header_buttonburger:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 2px;
            background-color: black;
            transition: top 0.15s ease;
            pointer-events: auto;
          }
          .header_buttonburger:before {
            top: calc(100% + 2px);
          }
          .header_buttonburger:after {
            top: calc(100% + 8px);
          }
          .container_header_buttonburger {
            position: absolute;
            right: 19px;
            top: 24px;
            padding-bottom:14px; /* <--that makes the difference */
          }
          .container_header_buttonburger:hover > .header_buttonburger:before {
            top: calc(100% + 4px);
          }
          .container_header_buttonburger:hover > .header_buttonburger:after {
            top: calc(100% + 12px);
          }
```